# Remove gap in Python Kivy kv-file

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy, kivy-language

I want to write a simple GUI with Kivy. I design the GUI with the *.kv-file, but I have a problem. There is always a gap between my elements (see picture, I colored the gap red). Can anyone tell me, how I have to change the *.kv-file, please?

GUI with gap I don't like:

[image: GUI with gap I don't like]

If I change the window-size with the mouse or set a window-size in the code, everything looks fine on my PC. But I want to use the App on other systems, too. So it should looks everywhere fine.

Here is my Code:

main.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget


class CalculationScreen(Screen):
    pass


class AnimWidget(Widget):
    pass


class Calculation(App):
    def build(self):
        screenmanager = ScreenManager()
        screenmanager.add_widget(CalculationScreen(name='calculation'))
        return screenmanager


def main():
    kv = Builder.load_file("calculation.kv")
    Calculation().run()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And the *.kv-file:

```
# Filename: calculation.kv

<CalculationScreen>:
    GridLayout:
        rows: 2
        cols: 2


        GridLayout:
            rows: 5
            cols: 3

            Label:
                text: "First one"
                size_hint: 1, None
                height: 35

            TextInput:
                size_hint: 1, None
                height: 35


            Label:
                text: "[ABC]"
                size_hint: 1, None
                height: 35

            Label:
                text: "Next one"
                size_hint: 1, None
                height: 35

            TextInput:
                size_hint: 1, None
                height: 35

            Label:
                text: "[DFG]"
                size_hint: 1, None
                height: 35

            Label:
                text: "Something else"
                size_hint: 1, None
                height: 35

            TextInput:
                size_hint: 1, None
                height: 35

            Label:
                text: "[KV]"
                size_hint: 1, None
                height: 35

            Label:
                text: "Another one"
                size_hint: 1, None
                height: 35

            TextInput:
                size_hint: 1, None
                height: 35

            Label:
                text: "[XY]"
                size_hint: 1, None
                height: 35

            Label:
                text: "The Last"
                size_hint: 1, None
                height: 35

            TextInput:
                size_hint: 1, None
                height: 35

            Label:
                text: "[ZZ]"
                size_hint: 1, None
                height: 35


        GridLayout:
            cols: 1
            rows: 1

            Image:
                source: 'toad.jpg'
                size_hint: 1, None
                height: 140

        GridLayout:
            cols: 1
            rows: 2

            GridLayout:
                cols: 4
                rows: 1

                Label:
                    text: 'First'
                    size_hint_y: None
                CheckBox:
                    id: 'first'
                    size_hint_y: None
                Label:
                    text: 'Second'
                    size_hint_y: None
                CheckBox:
                    id: 'second'
                    size_hint_y: None

            Button:
                size_hint: 0.4, 0.4
                pos_hint: {'x': 1, 'y': 1}
                text: 'Calculate'

        GridLayout:
            rows: 2
            cols: 1
            #size_hint_y: None

            Label:
                id: 'result'
                text: 'Result'

            Label:
                text: 'Version 1.0'
                text_size: self.size
                halign: "right"
```

Tanks you for help!

**Edit:**

Is it better to use FloatLayout?
I'm a little bit scared of using my app on devices with different display resolutions. Can I use FloatLayout and the app will look fine on every display resolution?

Answer (score 1):

i think you can add         spacing: (0, 0)  in the the
2 first grid layout GridLayout:
rows: 2
cols: 2
spacing: (0, 0)  # Add this line to remove the gap

```
    GridLayout:
        rows: 5
        cols: 3
        spacing: (0, 0)  # Add this line to remove the gap

        Label:
            text: "First one"
            size_hint: 1, None
            height: 35
```

Comment: Thanks for help. But 'spacing' didn't change anything. The window looks with 'spacing' like without 'spacing'. I think this is because "spacing (0, 0) is the default value. [Kivy Doc Spacing](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.gridlayout.html#kivy.uix.gridlayout.GridLayout.spacing)